# Face missing in edit mode but visible in object mode

Tags: modeling

I'm having a weird glitch i believe. I'm new to blender and was fiddling around, practicing with a random helmet mesh and added a boolean intersection into the helmet. After this, when I am in edit mode (with wire-frame turned on, a trigon in my mesh is not showing, but when i switch over to object mode the hole disappears. I checked face selection (hotkey 3) to see if there was a duplicate helmet or surface covering up the face but there is nothing. Is this a glitch? My blender file: https://gofile.io/d/zFCbER

[image: Empty Trigon]

[image: Trigon filled]

Comment: It's possible you accidently hid a single polygon in Edit Mode. Check by going back to Edit Mode and pressing Alt + h to unhide everything.

Comment: Welp, that just solved the problem... DOH.. Thank you so much